# remove line height from the second line

Tags: html, css

I have given line height of 60px for a tag but wen content is more, it goes to second line but even second line is taking line height of 60px. How do I remove line-height from  second line?

Here line height is necessary to vertically middle align the text to div.

```
a.pname
{ font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:14px; 
color:#000; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none; line-height:65px; 
float:left; background-color:#090; width:190px 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:first-line`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp) pseudoelement to select only the first line. Remove the `line-height` property from your style and add this

```
a.pname:first-line { line-height: 65px; }
```